# Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2'

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular

I am developing an node app with angular2 and gulp. I have written a component file login.ts as follows:

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {FormBuilder,  formDirectives } from 'angular2/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  injectables: [FormBuilder]
})
@View({
  templateUrl: '/scripts/src/components/login/login.html',
  directives: [formDirectives]
})

export class login {

}
```

And my bootstrap.ts file is:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';

import {login} from './components/login/login';

bootstrap(login);
```

but when I compile these files it gives me the following errors:

```
client\bootstrap.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2'.
client\components\login\login.ts(1,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2
client\components\login\login.ts(2,45): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/forms'.
```

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "watch": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true
    }
}
```

I have installed the typing for angular2 using:

```
tsd install angular2 --save
```

Please help to fix the error.

Comment: @View was dropped so this code is no longer valid in Angular2

Comment: I think its important to mention... There is a difference between importing from 'angular2' vs '@angular'. If you are using cdn (i.e., `<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/<version>angular2.dev.js">`), then you would import from 'angular2`. If you're installing angular2 as a dependency from npm, then you would import '@angular'. Also, Angular2 is currently in rc4 and there are a lot of changes that are happening. To get the latest changes for Angular2, I would recommend taking a look at the 5 Min Quickstart on the angular.io website.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

yups as said by @simon error is in imports. but for further imports i have posted this answer may be this is useful for others too.

```
import {Component, View, Directive, Input, Output, Inject, Injectable, provide} from 'angular2/core'; 

import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgClass, NgIf  NgForm, Control, ControlGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from 'angular2/common';

import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, Router, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';

import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, RequestOptions, Headers, Request, RequestMethod} from 'angular2/http'
```

## update -

`@View` is no more in angular2 now, so no need to import

```
import {view} from 'angular2/core'
```

## Update 2

As of angular2 is in RC so there is breaking change in all imports here is the list if all updated imports -

```
angular2/core -> @angular/core
angular2/compiler -> @angular/compiler
angular2/common -> @angular/common
angular2/platform/common -> @angular/common
angular2/common_dom -> @angular/common
angular2/platform/browser -> @angular/platform-browser-dynamic
angular2/platform/server -> @angular/platform-server
angular2/testing -> @angular/core/testing
angular2/upgrade -> @angular/upgrade
angular2/http -> @angular/http
angular2/router -> @angular/router
angular2/platform/testing/browser -> @angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing
```

Comment: if i do so /node_modules/angular2/typings/node/node.d.ts getting conflicted with typings\node\node.d.t

Comment: typings\node\node.d.ts is need for the express, mongoose

Comment: sorry i don't get you, but if you are talking about typings according to me there is no need to use typings in angular2 now because this is predefined in the librarys of angular2

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need to import `NgClass` and `NgIf` since these are built into Angular2.

Comment: yeah definitely @kimbaudi you don't need to import those but posting just for reference purpose.

Answer (score 24):

It changed module just ahead of going beta to

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
```

FYI: bootstrap also changed to

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
```

as a result a lot of the blog posts on the net are out of date :-(

Comment: if i do so /node_modules/angular2/typings/node/node.d.ts  getting conflicted with typings\node\node.d.ts

Comment: typings\node\node.d.ts is need for the express, mongoose

Comment: You may want to edit and repost your question, as your original question has been solved and your title won't attrat the typescript experts you need

Comment: i think it changed from `import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform-browser';` to `import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform-browser-dynamic';

Answer (score 4):

As per the new release of Angular2 rc1, you can update your package.json to

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    .....
 }
```

In addition to this also import as following in your component or container:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router, RouteParams} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
```

Answer (score 3):

Please note that as form Angular2 final release the correct answer is this.

```
import {Component, View, Directive, Input, Output, Inject, Injectable, provide} from 'angular/core'; 

import {bootstrap} from 'angular/platform/browser';

import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgClass, NgIf  NgForm, Control, ControlGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from 'angular/common';

import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, Router, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular/router';

import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, RequestOptions, Headers, Request, RequestMethod} from 'angular/http'
```

This is true as said in yups update 2 from above

```
angular2/core -> @angular/core
angular2/compiler -> @angular/compiler
angular2/common -> @angular/common
angular2/platform/common -> @angular/common
angular2/common_dom -> @angular/common
angular2/platform/browser -> @angular/platform-browser-dynamic
angular2/platform/server -> @angular/platform-server
angular2/testing -> @angular/core/testing
angular2/upgrade -> @angular/upgrade
angular2/http -> @angular/http
angular2/router -> @angular/router
angular2/platform/testing/browser -> @angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to access Component from wrong/old directory of node_modules.
Please access Component from

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
```

instead of :  `import { Component, View } from 'angular2/angular2';`

AND

Access bootstrap from bellow path :

```
import { bootstrap } from 'angular2/platform/browser';
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to Update Angular2 version in final version --

And then use like ----

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
```

there is a updated library like --- `'@angular/core'`

Answer (score 0):

import from ''angular2/angular2' was in previous version which no longer supported now .So Now we have to import the same from 'angular2/core'.For detail reference 
use (https://angular.io/guide/quickstart)

Comment: yup, quickstart is the best way to stay up-to-date with changes in Angular2

Answer (score 0):

**'angular2/angular2' is not a valid dependencies of angular2**

you have to first check package.json file "@angular/core" exist or not

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
    .....
 }
```

**see the component file like this and also you have too use formGroup as belove**

```
    import { Component, OnInit, DoCheck } from '@angular/core'
    import { Router } from '@angular/router'

    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms'

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-user-profile',
      templateUrl: './user-profile.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./user-profile.component.scss'],
    })
    export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {
      profileForm: FormGroup

      constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.profileForm = this.fb.group({
          firstName: ['', Validators.required],
          lastName: ['', Validators.required],
          email: ['', Validators.required],
          mobileNo: ['', Validators.required]
        });
    }
```

**than you have to import ReactiveFormsModule in app.module.ts file**

import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
without ReactiveFormsModule formGroup not work it make error

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { UserProfileComponent } from './user-profile.component';

import { UserProfileRoutingModule } from './user-profile-routing.module';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    UserProfileRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [UserProfileComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to kick of **angular2** project is using Angular **CLI**.

> The Angular CLI makes it easy to create an application that already works, right out of the box. It already follows our best practices!

please [check this](https://cli.angular.io/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "userForm",
  template: '<div><input type="text" name="name" [disabled]="flag"/></div>'
});

export class userForm{
 public flag = false; //boolean value: true/false
}
```

Answer (score -1):

- First update your angular2 liberies at packege.json.
- Second

  ```
   import {Component} from "@angular/core";
   import {FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";

   @Component({
    selector: "login",
    providers: [FormBuilder],
    templateUrl: "/scripts/src/components/login/login.html"
   })


   export class login {

   }
  ```