# Can't make ng properties work in Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm using Angular 2 RC1 and I'm trying to use `ngFor`. I've imported `import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';` and I know angular is working (I've tried to display a variable `<div>{{ myVar }}</div>` and it works)

I keep getting `Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known native property` when doing:

`<div *ngFor="let item of list">{{item}}</div>`.

I've tried to import `import {NgFor} from 'angular2/common';` and added it to my directives with no success.

The litterature online is confusing as it seems the Angular team has changed between beta versions and RC...

Comment: what's list? can you show us your component code? And RC1 should be imported via `@angular/core`. you're importing the beta version.

Comment: PS: -No need to import external `NgFor` all these imports are already in the CORE_DIRECTIVES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing from 'angular2/core' instead of '@angular/core', so you have to use '#' instead 'let':

```
<li *ngFor="#item of list">
  {{ item }}
</li>
```

Comment: Good point! I just realized that and changed to `@angular/core`. The problem now is that I'm getting a 500 error from the server (I did the `npm install` and added all the @angular to my package.json)

Comment: Try cloning from https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git and start your project from that

Comment: Thanks, I didn't expect so many changes in the initialization phase. Please close the `li`

Comment: @ncohen For more List of updated Imports you can see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34697758/5043867