# angular 2 example error

Tags: angular, browserify, babeljs

I'm gettin an error running my angular 2 app, this is my app.js

```
import 'zone.js/lib/browser/zone-microtask';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import { Component, View, bootstrap } from 'angular2/angular2';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello-app'
})
@View({
  directives: [HelloComponent],
  template: `
    <div>
      <hello-component></hello-component>
    </div>
  `
})
class HelloApp { }

bootstrap(HelloApp, []);
```

and this is the error:

> { [SyntaxError: /code/angular2-example/app.js: Unexpected token (7:0)
>   while parsing file: /code/angular2-example/app.js]   pos: 190,   loc:
>   Position { line: 7, column: 0 },   _babel: true,   codeFrame:
>   '\u001b[0m   5 | \u001b[36mimport\u001b[39m \u001b[32m{\u001b[39m
>   HelloComponent \u001b[32m}\u001b[39m from
>   \u001b[31m\'./hello.component\'\u001b[39m\u001b[1m;\u001b[22m\n   6 |
>   \n>  7 |
>   \u001b[7m@\u001b[27mComponent\u001b[34m\u001b[1m(\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\u001b[32m{\u001b[39m\n
>   | ^\n   8 |   selector\u001b[1m:\u001b[22m
>   \u001b[31m\'hello-app\'\u001b[39m\n   9 |
>   \u001b[32m}\u001b[39m\u001b[34m\u001b[1m)\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\n  10 |
>   \u001b[7m@\u001b[27mView\u001b[34m\u001b[1m(\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\u001b[32m{\u001b[39m\u001b[0m',
>   filename: 'code/angular2-example/app.js',

but I don't see it. please can you help me. I am just starting with angular 2.

Comment: What Angular2 version are you using? `@View()` was removed months ago. Also what are the imports fro `zone-microtask` and `reflect-metadata` supposed to do?

Comment: For latest updated list of imports see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34697758/5043867

Answer (score 0):

your import statement is wrong!

```
   import { Component, View, bootstrap } from 'angular2/angular2';
```

import it from "@angular/core'

```
   import {Component} from '@angular/core';
   import (bootstrap) from 'angular2/platform.browser';
```

Component is imported from angular/core, View is no more a class in angular

Comment: For more latest list of imports see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34697758/5043867